# How do i save the result in a Vertical direction

Tags: python, list

```
#This is a solarcell simulator.



def save(result):
    with open('text.txt', 'w') as file:
       file.write(result)                                    


def main():

result = []

while True:
    val=int(input("Do you want to check a new latitude? 1.yes  2.No" ))

    if val == 1:
        print("lets go")

        lat=latitude()

        result.append(calc(lat))



    elif val==2:
        print ("Bye!")
        spara(str(result))
        break
    else:
        print("yes or no")
```

This is what I get in the `text.txt` file

```
[(1, 289.4736790328647), (2, 301.5078692306731)]
```

but this is what I want

```
[(1, 289.4736790328647) 
(2, 301.5078692306731)]
```

Comment: You could improve your question by cutting out all the irrelevant code and only focus on the few lines your question is about.

Comment: Don't edit your question to be a new question. Just create a new one..

Answer (score 0):

if `result` is a list of tuples then this would work:

```
file.write('[' + '\n'.join(map(str,result)) + ']')
```

Comment: But with this i can only save to result i want to be able to save as many as i want

Comment: oops, replace z with result, and i did not understand the point you're making. this one does save many tuples of latitude